# I created a landing page with Unbounce; is it OK to copy the code and use it elsewhere?

Tags: copyright, software, intellectual-property

I used Unbounce to create a landing page but I made a blank page and built a design myself using their page builder. I didn't use their templates or anything.

I want to move my domain to a new server so I can do other things like install a blog but I can't do that when my domain is pointed to Unbounce so I want to move it.

I still want my landing page up on the .com, just moved to another server.

Is it ok to copy the source code that was built using Unbounce's page builder and use the exact same code on my new server?

Comment: Just FYI...  aside from the legal.... most "page builders" at hosting companies throw in a lot of proprietary code/markup. Often you'll find copying a page retains that markup and your page will still point to the host at times. It's just good practice to rebuild the markup/code without the proprietary "page builder".

Answer (score 1):

Usually, no. If you have agreed to terms whereby you are granted a license of some kind to copy their work, then you may be permitted to do this.

Otherwise, in all countries party to the Berne Convention, copyright vests automatically in the creator of a work or an assignee upon its creation and protects its form from copying by another without authorisation.